# Вопрос про авторизацию FireBase

Tags: java, firebase

Мне нужно сделать авторизацию по номеру телефона. В принципе с задачей я уже справился следующим образом:

```
private EditText etLastName;
private EditText etFirstName;
private TextView tvTextErrors;
private Button button;

private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 123;
private static final String TAG = "MyApp_Authorization";
private FirebaseUser user;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    etLastName = findViewById(R.id.regFamily);
    etFirstName = findViewById(R.id.regName);
    tvTextErrors = findViewById(R.id.regTextErrors);
    button = findViewById(R.id.regButton);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
    user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (Objects.equals(user, null)) {
        Authorization();
    } else {
        if (!Objects.equals(user.getDisplayName(), null) && !Objects.equals(user.getDisplayName(), "")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Global.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
}

private void Authorization() {
    //Если входим в первый раз или срок кода доступа истек
    List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build());
    startActivityForResult(
            AuthUI.getInstance()
                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                    .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                    .setLogo(R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp)
                    .setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)
                    .build(),
            RC_SIGN_IN);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        //IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //Если есть подключение к сети интернет
            //После подтверждения по СМС
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

            etFirstName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            etLastName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            button.setText(getString(R.string.toRegister));

            if (!Objects.equals(user.getDisplayName(), null) && !Objects.equals(user.getDisplayName(), "")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Global.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        } else {
            //Если нет подключения к сети интернет
            tvTextErrors.setText("Проверьте подключение к сети и повторите попытку!");
            etFirstName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            etLastName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            button.setText("Повторить попытку");
            Log.d(TAG, "Не удалось получить данные пользователя при попыткуе обновления Фамилии и Имени");
        }
    }
}

public void toRegister(View view) {
    if (user != null) {
        //Проверка входных данных
        boolean access = true;
        String textError = "";
        String strFirstName = etFirstName.getText().toString();
        String strLastName = etLastName.getText().toString();
        String strFullName = strLastName + " " + strFirstName;
        if (strFirstName.replace(" ", "").length() <= 1 || strLastName.replace(" ", "").length() <= 1) {
            textError += "Слишком короткое имя/фамилия.\r\n";
            access = false;
        }
        if (!access) {
            tvTextErrors.setText(textError);
            return;
        } else {
            tvTextErrors.setText("");
        }
        //Если данные были введены верно, сохраняем имя пользователя на сервере авторизации
        UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                .setDisplayName(strFullName)
                .build();

        user.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Global.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            tvTextErrors.setText("Не удалось завершить последний шаг авторизации, проверьте подключение к сети и повторите попытку.");
                        }
                    }
                });
    } else {
        //Если не удалось получить данные пользователя из-за отсутствия подключения к сети Интернет
        Authorization();
        Log.d(TAG, "Не удалось получить данные пользователя при попыткуе обновления Фамилии и Имени");
    }
}
```

Как я понял после авторизации данные для быстрой авторизации хранятся в телефоне и получаю я их методом `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();`. Так вот у меня вопрос. Есть ли срок годности у этих данных? Или, если устройство утеряно мной, то злоумышленник может через месяц открыть это приложение и автоматически залогиниться без проверки по номеру?

Если у данных пользователя `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();` нет срока годности, то я могу как-то реализовать авторизацию через токен со сроком годности, но без использования своего сервера?

Не уверен, что у меня хватит ума и времени, чтобы разобраться с установкой и настройкой сервера для администрирования учетных записей в FireBase, чтобы использовать CustomToken. Надеюсь, что доступно описал проблему. Если есть другие простые решения данной проблемы, то они тоже пригодятся.

Заранее благодарен за ответы, особенно подробные и с примерами!)

Comment: Подключил Google Cloud Platform, но все очень запутано. Не понимаю как тут сервер грамотно развернуть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пришлось все же делать сервер по другой причине. А аутентификация по токенам без сервера невозможна.